# Prompted to accept incoming network connections for an application defined in firewall

Tags: macos, mac, firewall

Each time I boot, I am prompted whether I want to accept incoming connections for the application.

I have already added manually the application to

```
System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall -> Advanced
```

Any ideas how I can stop this prompting and permanently accept that I want to allow incoming connections?